# Splitting a file into separate files based on a keyword on a particular column of each header line

Tags: bash, git

I would like to create separate files based on the first chromosome mentioned in the header line. There are 24 chromosomes mentioned in the header line and their sequences are mentioned in the next 2 lines. The file architecture is:
header
human sequences
other genome sequences

However, all the chromosomal sequences are merged within a single file that I want to split into individual chromosome files along with their respective sequence pairs. I created a Python script for this but uploading the big merged file on the cluster takes a huge amount of time and often leads to a connection error. So, I want to do it using a Bash script.

**The idea is to search for 'chrY' (or any chrome name) on the 2nd column of the header line and then paste that header line along with their 2 following sequence lines into a separate file.**

```
2057524 chrY 68 170 chrX 23685 23787 - 4125
TCCAGACTACCAGACACAAGACATTACACATTGTAATGCATTAAATGCATAGTTTTAACAGTAATAATTTAAAAGAGATTTAGAATTTTATAATGTTTGGAAA
TCAAGGCCCCGGGCTACCTGACATTACCCTCATTAATGCATGAAATGCAGAATATTAACATGAGCAATTTAAGATGAACTTAAGATTCTGTAATGTTTAGAAA
```

**Details:**

```
2057524 chrY (human chromosome) 68 170 chrX (other genome chromosome) 23685 23787 - 4125 -> header line
TCCAGACTACCAGACACAAGACATTACACATTGTAATGCATTAAATGCATAGTTTTAACAGTAATAATTTAAAAGAGATTTAGAATTTTATAATGTTTGGAAA (human sequence)
TCAAGGCCCCGGGCTACCTGACATTACCCTCATTAATGCATGAAATGCAGAATATTAACATGAGCAATTTAAGATGAACTTAAGATTCTGTAATGTTTAGAAA (other genome sequence)
```

**For testing:**

```
2057521 chr10 57211219 57211230 NW_007726181v1 1018288 1018299 + 575
CTGGGCACTATG
CTGAGCGCGGTG

2057522 chr2 57211231 57214400 NW_007726181v1 1018406 1021615 + 116172
GTTTtgagcttgt----acccagcgctgcttttgccttgctctgtgaccccaggcaagctgcctcacctctctgggccagtttccccat-cgtacagtggTGCTGCACACCCTGGCCCTGGCCC-CGAGGTGGCTGGGAGGTGGCTCCTCAAACAGCCGCTTTCTCATCAGTGCCCGGTGCTGGGT-CAGGGATCGACTGAGGCTCT--GAGCTAACTAGGAAACACAGTGGCCTTG--GAGGGCTGGGGAGTGTCATGGGGGTG---GGGACAGGGAGCCACCGGTCGCATGTGACTGAACTCTT-----------------CACCCCAGTCTGTGGCTTTCCCGTTGCAGTGAGAGCCACGAGCCAAGGTGGGCACTTGATGTCGGATCTCTTCAACAAGCTGGTCATGAGGCGCAAGGGTAGGAGGCAGGGCCGCTGCCCGCCCTGGGTCGGCACCT---------------TGTAATTCTGTCCTGCCTTTTTCTTCCTGTATTTAAGTCTCCGGGGGCTGGGGGAATCAGGGTTTCCCACCAACCACCCTCACTCAGCCTTTTCCC-TCCAGGCATCTCTGGGAAAGGACCT------GGGGCTGGTGAGGGGCCCGGAGGAGCCTTTGCCCGCGTGTCAGACTCCATCCCTCCTGTGCCCCCACCGCAACAGCCACAGGCAGAGGAGGACGAGGACGACTGGGAATCCTAGGGGGCTCCATGACACCTTCCCCCCCAGACCCAGACTTGGGCTGTTGCTCTGACATGGACACAGCCAGGACAAGCTGCTCAGACCTGCTTCCCTGG-GAGGGGGTGACGGAACCAGCACTG---------TGTG-GAGACCAGCTTCAAGGAGCGGAAGGCTGGCTTGAGGCCACACAGCTGGGGCG---GGGACTT-CTGTCTGCCTGTGCTCCATGGGGGGACGGCTCCACC--------CAGCCTGCGCCACTGTGTTCTTAAGAGGCTTCCAGAGAAAACGGCA-CACCAATCAATA-----------AAGAACTGAGCAGAAACCAACAGTGTGCTTTTAATAAAGGACCTCTAGCTGTGCAGGATGCAAACGTCTCGGGGTCAGTGACTGCCTCCTGCCCCTGTTGGTCCCTAGGCAGTGGGGGCAGAAGCTCCCAGCTGACCTG------TTTCTCTGGGAGAGAAGGGCAGTCAGCAGGGGCAGCTGTTGCAGATGGGAGGAATAG--------TCTCCCACA----AAAAAGGTTTCAGTGACAGACACGGGGTCTCTAAAAATAGTCATGCTGAGAGCCCAATGGCCCTTGGCACAATTGCTGGTGTTGGGGTAGAAGATGTCTTGGAGTTTGCTCAAGTGGTTGAGAGGGAGGGAGGTGCCATCAACTT---GGAGGAACTGGCACCAAGCCAGGGAGATAGAAATCCAGGCAAGGCTGTGGGGCAGGTTAGGGAGCAAGGCTGCAGGGGTGACTCAGGAAGAAGGTGGGGGAGGTGACAAGCCCCCAGGCAGGGGCCCTGTGGCC-------------ATGGGGATCTTTTTAAATTGAGACTAGGGGGTGAATAGTCCAGGGCAGCTAACTTTAGTTATTATAGAAAG-GGCAGTAGCAGATGGGTCTG-CTCCGTCTCGCTTCTAAGAAGGTGG---------------GCAGGACAAATGGCAGCCTCCTGCAGAGGCCCAGTGAGAAGCCTGGCCC-------TCGGCCAC-----ACAGGATGGAAGACAGATTGGATTCCACAGAGGGGAGCTGCCCTGGGAAGATCTCACGGATGGCCAGGACCCACCATTTCTTCGGGGTTCCCCT-GTTTTCTCCAACGGGCACTAATGCCTGTGCCTGGGTCCTGGCAACAC----------------------TCTGGACTCCACACTCT--TCTGGGTTTCACCTTTGTA-GCAGGATCCCTGCAGATCAGGCCCATGACAAACACCGTCTCCAGCGGGCAGAGCAAAGGAAGGGCGCAGCGCCAGGCAGTGGTGCAGCTGCCTGTCAGGAAGAGGCCTACTTCT---GGTGAAACTGGGCAGAC---AAAAGGCAGTGAGAAATGTGATCTCGGGGTGGTGGAGGCTC-TAGGGAAAGGAAAAGGCAGGAGTGAACTTCCACACAGCAGCAATGGCAGAACCAAAGGTGGCTTTGACCTCCACGAGGGCTCAGATCCAGGCCAACAGCTTGTCCAGGACAGGGTGCCGGGTGTATCACTAATCCAGGAGCACTATGCTGGCAGAATCCCTTTGGTGCCTGATGGCCCTGCCTTCGTGGGAACAGAGGCTAAGGCTTTGAGTTACAGCTGCCTCCCCAACAGTGCATCCCCTTCTCCTTCCTCAGCCTCAGGTAGGAGACAGGGCAGGCAACCCCCCTTTCCTCTTCTCCCCTTCTCCAGCCCCTGTCTGTCCACCCAGCTGGAGGCAG--CCAGGCTTGCCTATGGACTGGTTGACAGCCTTCATGCACAGGTTCTCCACCAGAGCCTTTCTTGGGGGCCCCTGGCT--GGGCTCTGAGCTGGGAGTGAAGGGGATGACCCATGCGGACTGTTTGCTGC-------------TTGTAGCTTTCCCTGGGA-AAGACTCTGCCAGGCCTTGGAGCCAGACCAGGAGGCTTTATAGGCCACTGCAAGCAGCAGGGCTCCAGATGACATCACAGGGAATATCAAGAGGGTGTGGAGGGGCATCGAAGCCTCTCCAGGAG---ACAG----GAGAC---GCCGGCCCAGTAGAGCCCTAGGGGCGACGCCACTCCCACTCACTGTCTACTCTCCTCTCACCTCTGCAACACTGGGGACACTCACAAGATTGTGATCCAAGTCGGCCGTCGTCTTCTGCAGCTCTGGAGACCTGATGCTGGGGAAGGGCATGCCTGGCATCACCACACACCTGGGAGGAGACAGGAGCCTG-GGGCCGGTGG---------------------GCCCACACATCACCAGCTGCTCCGTTCTACCATTTCTTCAGCCCTCTTGGCTGTGC-CTGCGGCTCTGCCCCTCCCCTCTCTGCACCTACCACCCAGAGAGGGCTTGTTGAGCTCAGAGATCCCACCTAGGCCAATCCACTGGGTTCTGTGGCAGCGATGGCCTGCCTGATCTTCCACCTGCTCTCCCAGGGCCAAAGCCAGACCTGCTGAGCCCCTCCC--TCCAGCCGGCTGGT-CTGAGCAGTCACAGCCCGGCTTTGGGCTCCGATGGCAGCAGATGGCAGGTAGGGGTCCAGCTGCTGG-AGCGAGGGCCGGCCACGTATCACAG-CCAAGGAGATGAGCACAAG--CACTACTTACTGGCCTAGGTTGTCAGAGAAGTTGATGCTCTCACTCATCTTTCCTCCAATC
gtcctgagtttgccaaggcccagctctgcttctgacttgtcctgtg-----agacaaagtgcctaacgtctttgggccagtttcctcatccccacagtggggctgcaca-cctgcccgtgtcttacaggatggccgtgatgt------tca-----CCATTTTCTTAT-AGTACCCACTGCCAGATACACGGACAGACCAAAGCTCCCAGAGCTCA-TGGTGAACAT-GTGGCTGTGGAGAGGGCTGGGGACTGTTGCAGGGGCAAGTGAGCCAAGAGGGCACTGG-CGACTGGGCCTGGAGCCTCCCGACTTGGCCCCCGCACCCTCCCACCTGCAGCTTTCCTCTTGCAGTGAGAGCCACAAGCCAAGGTGGAGACCTGATGTCAGATCTCTTCAACAAGCTGGTCATGAGGCGCAAAGGTAGGAGGCAGAGGGGCCGCC--TTCAGGGCAGGGGCCTCAGGGTGTCCTGCAGTGTACTTCTGTTCTGCCTCTTTCTTCCTGTTTTTAAATCTTCAGGGGCTGTGTGACCTGGGGCCTCCATACACCCTCCCTCA--CAGCCTTTTCCCTTCCAGGTATCTCCGGGAAAGGACCTGGAACAGGGGCCAGCGAGGGGCCAGGAGGAGCCTTCGCCCGAATGTCAGACTCCATCCCGCCTCTGCCTCCCCCACAGCAGCCAC---CGGGAGAGGACGAGGATGACTGGGAATCCTAGGGGTCT-CAGCACTCCTTCCTCCCCCAACCCAGACTTGGGCTGTGGCCCTGAGACAGACACAGCTGGGACA--------------GCCCCCTTGGTGAGACAGGGATGGTG-CAGGACTGCCCTACGTCTGTGCTGGGCCTTCTTCAGGGAGCGGGTAGGTTGCATGAAACCATAAGTGTGGGGTGGGAGGGGCTCGCTCTCCACCTGTGCCCCACCGTGTGCCTGCTCTACCCACCCCTTCAGCGTGTGCTCCTCTTCCCGAAAGAGACT--CGAAGAAAACAGCACCATGAATCAATAAAGGACGATGTAAGAACTGAGCATAAACCAACAGTGCACTTTTAATTAAGGAGTCAAGGCTGGGTGGCTTGCAAACATCTGAGAACCAGTGACTG--TCCTGCCCC-GTGGGTCTCCAGGCAAT-GGGGCAGAACATCTGAGTGGACCAGGGCCCCTTGCACTGGCTCGAAGGTGCAGTCAGCAGGGGCAGCTGCTGTGGATGGGAGGGAGGGAGGGAGATGTTCCCACGGGATAAAGATGTCTCAGTGACAGACATGGGGTCTCTAAAAATAGTTGTGCTGAGAGCCTAATGGCCCTTGGCATAATTGCTGATGTCAGGGTAGAAGGTGTCTTGGAGTTTGCTCAAGTGCCTGAGAGGGAAGGAGGTGCCATCAACTTGGAGGAGGAATGGGAGCCAAGCCAGAGAGA-AAAGCCCTGCGCGGAGCTGTGGAGCAGACCA--GAGCACAGCTG-----------------------------------AGGCTGGCAGG-AGGAGCCGTGTGGACAGCAGAACTAGAAATGGGGAACGTTTTGAGT------------GTGAAATGTCTAGAACAGCTCATTTTAGCTAGGATGAACAGAGGCAG-----GATGGGCCTGTTTCCATCGGACCTCTGAGAAGGTGGCTACTGAGAAAACATGCAGGACAGAAG-----CTGCAGCAGAACACCGGGCAGGAGCCTGGCGCGGCCAGTGTGGCCACACTAAACAGGGAGGAAGATGCAATGG------CAGGGAGCAGCTGCCCTGCAGTGGGCTCAAGGGCAGTCAGGACCCACTGTTTACTCAGGATCAACCTAGTTTTCTCCAACTGGCTTTTCTACCTGGGCCTGCATGCGGGCAGCCCACTGATGCTGGAAGGGGGCTGGTCTGGACCTCACACTCTACACCTGGTTTCACCTTCTTAGGCAGGATCCCTGTAGACCAGGCCCAAGACAAACACCATTCTAAGTGGGCAGGGTAAAGGAAGAGC------CCGGGC--TGGTGCAGCCATCCATCAGGAACGGCCAAACTTCTCCCGATGAAACTGGGGAGATGGGAAAAGGCAGTGAGAGACTAGATCTCAGGGTGA-GCAGGCTCGGGGGGGAAGGAAAAGGCAGGACTGACCTTACGCATAGCAGCAACAGCATGGCCAAAGGTGGCCTTGACCTCCACACGGTCTCGGATCCAGCCTGGCAGCTTTGCCAGGATGGGTGGGCGGGCATATCGCTGGTCTAGGAGCACTATGCTGGCAAAATCCCTCTGGTGCCTGATGGCTCTGCCTGGATGGGAACAGAATTTGGGGCTCCTAGGTAAA-------------------ATCCTCTCCTGTGACTTCATTCTC-------------------CAACCACCCAT--CTGTACTCC----------CAACTATCCATCCTGACAGCCAGGAGCAGTCCCAGGCTTACCTATAGATTGGTTGACAGCCTTCATACACAGATTCTCCACCAAGGCCTTCCCTGGTGGGGGCTGGCCTGGGGTTCTGGGCTGGGAAGGGTAGAAAGGACCTATCAGAACTGTTCCTTACCTCCTGTCTAGTGTTCTAGCTCTCCCTGGGAGAAGAGCCTGCCAGGCTTTGGAGCAAGACCAGGCAGCTTCACAAGCCAGTGCCAGCAGCTGG------CACGATGTCATGGAGAAGGTCAAGAGGGGGACAGGAAACACC--AGCATGGCAAGGAAGTCACAGCTACAAGACCCTGCTATCTCAG------CCTAGGGAATACACCACACTTCCCCCCGGCC--CTCTCCTCAT-CCTCTGGAATCCTGGAGGTACTCACAAGGGTCTGATCCAAGTAGGTCATCTTCTCTTGTAGTTCTGGAGAGTTGATGTTGGGGTAGGGCATGCCCACCATCACTACACACCTAGGTGGAGATGCACGCCGATGGGCATGTGGCCTCACACTCACTGAGTCCTCACCCACATGCCACCGACTGCT--GCTCTACCTCTGCTGCCG--CTCTTGGCTATGCTCGGCAGCTCTACCCTCCGCATC-CCGTACCTACCACCTGGAAAGGATTTTTTCAGCTAAGAGACCCAGTCTAAGCCAATGAACATAGTCCTGATAAGGTTATGGTTTGCCCCATTTTCCATCTGCTCT-CAAAGGCCCAATCCAGAGTTGCTGAAACACTTCCCGCCTGGCTGCCTGATCCTGAGCAGC--CAGCCTGGGTGCAGACTCAGATGGCATCAGATTGCAGGT-GGGGCCCAGCTGCTGGAAGTGAGGAGTAGCCAGGTGTCATAGCCCCAGGAGAGAAGGAGAGGACCACTACTTACCGGCCTAGGTTGTCAGAGAAGTTAATCCCTTCACTCATCTTTCCTCCAACC

2057523 chrY 57214466 57215088 NW_007726181v1 1023265 1023919 + 29358
GGCCCATCCCACTCTAGGCATGGCTCCTCTCCACAGGAAAACTCCACTCCAGTGCTCAGCTTGCACCCTGGCACAGGCCAGCAGTTGCT---GGAAGTCAGACACCTGCAGATCAAGACCACAGCATCAAGACCCTGTGACCTCTCAAAGGCCTGGTGGAAAGGA--------------CACGG-----------GAAGTCTGGGCTAAGAGACAGCAAATACACATGAACAGAAAGAAGAGGTCAAAGAAAA--GGCTGACGGCAAGTTAACAAAAAGAAA--AATGGTGAATGATACCCGGTGCTGGCAATCTCGTTTAAACTACATGCAGGAACAGCAAAGGAAATCCGGCAAATTT-GCGcagtcattctcaacaccggccatgcagcaaaatcatcagtggaaatttaaaaaaatacacgtggccaggccccagcccaaatcact-aataagaatctccaggg-CTtcacctgttagactggcaaaaaatccaaaag--taaacactttgtggagaaacaggcactcctagacattgctggtgggatacagaacagtacaattctga------------tggtaatcagttaacaaattaaacatatttattttatacttttaaacccaggaatcccatatttaggagtctactgagaccaaacagc
GGCTCGCTCCGCCCGGGTCACA-CTCCTCACCGCAGGAGAACTCCACCAC-TCGCTCAGCCTCAGCCCCAGCGCACGCCAGCAGCTGCTCCCGGAAGTCAGACACCTGCAGA------CCACAATGGCAGGGCCCTGTGACCTCCCAGAGGCACAGGGGAGAAGAACCTCAGGCCTCGGCATGGAGGGCAAGACAGAAGTCTGGGCTGGAAGGCAGCAAGTACGTACAAACAGAAAAAAGAGCTAAAAAAAAAAAGGCTAACAACAAATTAACAATAATAAATAAATTGTTAATGATATCCAGTGTTGGCAGTTTCATTTAAGCTACTGGTAGAAACAGCAAAGGAAATCTGGCAAACTTGGCAcagtgattctcaaccctggctatgcatcaaaaccagcagtgggaatttaaaaaaatacACATGGCCCAGCCACAGTCCAAACTACTGAATAACAATCTCCAGGGttttcacctaccaaattggc---aaatccgaaagtttaaccactctgtggagaaaaaggcatttttaaacattgctggtgcaatacagaatagtacaactcttacataggggaatttgacaat-acttaacaaattaaatgga-----tttttactttttaactcaggaatctcatatctgggactccacccagaatacacagc

2057524 chrX 68 170 NW_007727164v1 23685 23787 - 4125
TCCAGACTACCAGACACAAGACATTACACATTGTAATGCATTAAATGCATAGTTTTAACAGTAATAATTTAAAAGAGATTTAGAATTTTATAATGTTTGGAAA
TCAAGGCCCCGGGCTACCTGACATTACCCTCATTAATGCATGAAATGCAGAATATTAACATGAGCAATTTAAGATGAACTTAAGATTCTGTAATGTTTAGAAA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$2` denotes the 2nd column
- `"chr19"` means we are searching for only details associated with `"chr19"`
- `{c=3}c-->0` commands to output the next 2 lines of the searched pattern

```
awk '$2=="chr19"{c=3}c-->0' file > chr19_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `grep` with the `-A` switch, which tells it to also include lines after the match. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1

for i in `seq 1 20`; do
  grep -A2 "chr$i " $file > seq_$i
done

grep -A2 "chrX " $file > seq_X
grep -A2 "chrY " $file > seq_X
```

Then execute with:

```
./extract.sh myfile
```